# How can we change Final variable ones we initialize?

Tags: java, keyword, final

How can we change Final variable ones we initialize? 
can any explain with example.how can we change final keyword

```
class Demo{  

   final int MAX_VALUE=99;
   void myMethod(){  
      MAX_VALUE=101;
   }  
   public static void main(String args[]){  
      Demo obj=new  Demo();  
      obj.myMethod();  
   }
```

}

Comment: you can't. that's why it 's declared final. If it was a mutable datatype, you could 've used its setters, but for immutable types and primitives, there's nothing you can do. Or, you could just remove the 'final'

Comment: If you want to be able to change a field, why make it `final`?

Comment: first of all I would really advise against doing this sort of things. As said in the comment if you want to change this value then do not make it final. BUT, if you want to, you can change it using java reflection.
A quick search on google will help you find this, as for example [this article](http://java-performance.info/updating-final-and-static-final-fields/).

Comment: In Interview the question I ask how can change final keyword variable?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the final variable for every instance of the class using blank final variable.

Example:

```
public class Main {

private final int no;

Main(int no){
    this.no = no;
}}
```